# mongodb in nodejs return undefined when trying to connect to collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when I write this code below I get:

```
Connected correctly to DB
undefined 
undefined
```

I have collection named users, so this sould not happened... why is the happening?

Thanks

```
var url = 'mongodb://user:pass@ds023475.mlab.com:23475/small-talkz';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return db.close();
    }

    console.log("Connected correctly to DB.");
    // update a record in the collection
    console.log(db.collection("users"));
    console.log(db.users); 

    return db.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need to `.find()` what it is you want from the collection. However, it is strange that it returns `undefined`. Try this code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {

  if(err) throw err;   
  db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
       console.log(collections);   
  }); 
});
```

to see what collection names the current database has. Perhaps it doesn't exist?

Otherwise, try finding the collection elements, as shown in the [docs example](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/query/#query-for-all-documents-in-a-collection).

Comment: Thanks I got not results printed the log.. any idea why?

Comment: Can you access the database through the command line/an interface? You'll need to let me know if it's a remote or local database and what OS you're using, if you need help doing that.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am able to acces the DB using mongo shell.. just the node js driver is giving me trouble...

Comment: Okay, in the command line, enter Mongo's shell by typing "mongo" (as you know probably!). Then `show dbs`. Find the database you want, then type `use DBNAME`, and then `db.getCollectionNames()`. Find the collection you want, then `db.COLLECTIONNAME.find({})`. This should give you the complete database contents. If it's empty, maybe you have an issue within the code that describes how you're saving the data you expected to be in there.